# How to continue with the loop when then XPATH changes based on the ids found or not

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am running a loop to the capture dates based on the id. When the id is passed in the loop the XPATH changes based on whether the id is found or not. If the id is not found my loop crashes even after using `try` and `except`. I have used multiple `try and excepts` to avoid the error. Have tried `if and else` no avail.

```
for i in ids:
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="print_area"]/table/tbody/tr[16]/td[1]/a').click()
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="print_area"]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[3]/a').click()
        # searching for an id.
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_cphMain_txtEmprAcctNu"]').send_keys(i)
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_cphMain_btnSearch').click()
        except NoSuchElementException as e:
            continue
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_cphMain_grdAgentEmprResults"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/a').click()
        except NoSuchElementException as e:
            continue
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="print_area"]/table/tbody/tr[8]/td[3]/a').click()
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="print_area"]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[1]/a').click()
        #copying the and storing the date
        subdate = driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_cphMain_frmViewAccountProfile_lblSubjectivityDate').text
        subjectivitydate.append(subdate)
        #exiting current details
        driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_ULinkButton4').click()
        sleep(1)
    except NoSuchElementException as e:
        continue
```

This is the XPATH that changes based on whether a value is present or not.

if id is present the XPATH is `//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_cphMain_grdAgentEmprResults"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/a'`

if the id is not found the XPATH is  `//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_cphMain_grdAgentEmprResults"]/tbody/tr/td`

How do control the xpath based on id found or not so that my loop does not crash.

Regards,
Ren.

Comment: Show the error.

Comment: This is the error message that is printed when the id is not found. `NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element. //*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_cphMain_grdAgentEmprResults"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/a`

Comment: When i check the XPATH where is shows the message on the site " No Records found..."  it is different to the error message. This is the XPATH `'//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_cphMain_grdAgentEmprResults"]/tbody/tr/td'` that is reflected

Comment: How do you import NoSuchElementException? `from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException`?

Comment: Use try Catch block with NoSuchElementExcetion.

Comment: @AlexeyDolgopolov I have already imported `from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException. This error continues post having that.

Comment: could this issue be because i am using an absolute XPATH. Instead of a relative one. Any suggestions how to build a relative XPATH.

Comment: I doubt that. Your problem, as I see it, not in xpath but in `try except` block not catching needed exception. You could use any xpath that isn't on the page (e.g. '//fakeelement') and should end up at `except` clause. And one outer `try except` block shoud be sufficient.

Comment: Try comment out inner `try except` blocks. Leave the outer one only. After `except NoSuchElementException` clause add 'catch all' `except Exception as e:\n print(e.__class__)\n print(e)\n raise`. ('\n' - newline, of course) What output will be?

Comment: Thanks. Used if condtion and broke it down so it worked